# Update query in Cassandra 2.3

Tags: php, cassandra

**This is My Table structure as follows**

```
CREATE TABLE manage_files_log (
    account_sid uuid,
    file_type text,
    file_sid timeuuid,
    date_created timestamp,
    file_description text,
    file_name text,
    status int,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((account_sid, file_type), file_sid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (file_sid DESC)
```

**in this table I want to update my records with query**

```
UPDATE manage_files_log SET url='$url' WHERE account_sid =e40daea7-b1ec-088a-fc23-26f67f2052b9 AND file_type ='json' AND file_sid=961883e0-208f-11e6-9c41-474a6606bc87;
```

**but it is inserting new record instead of updating existing record.**

**please help Me**

**below is the example of data in table where I want to update the url column value**

```
account_sid                          | file_type | file_sid                             | date_created             | file_description | file_name | status | url
--------------------------------------+-----------+-------------------    -------------------+--------------------------+------------------+--------    ---+--------+-----
 e40daea7-b1ec-088a-fc23-26f67f2052b9 |      json | e15e02f0-20ab-11e6-9c41-474a6606bc87 | 2016-05-22 00:00:00+0000 |      descripton  |  testUrl1 |      1 |
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the table before running the query? In your case, all of account_sid, file_type and file_sid must be the same in order for Cassandra to update the existing record. Using UPDATE won't stop it from inserting a new record if the primary key is unique.

Comment: I updated the question please see the example above.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your question.
If your update contains the complete PRIMARY KEY, then what do you mean that a new record is created. Can you post both the records that are created? It is impossible to have two rows with the same primary key.

Comment: Also, there is no such version as Cassandra 2.3.  The next major version after 2.2 is 3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, there's one thing you have to know about cassandra: Update or insert don't exist. I know, you write, in your query, update or insert, but it's the same. It's called Upsert. You might think: Whaaat? But there's a reason for this: Cassandra is a masterless distributed database system. You have, generally, no transactions. If you insert a value to node1 and want to update it after 10ms on node2, it could happen that your first value isn't on node2. With a hard UPDATE, your second operation will fail. But cassandra ignores this fact and writes the values to node2. After a time node2 and node1 will synchronizing their values. At this stage node1 gets the right values from node1. (Cassandra uses an internal column timestamp for synchronizing)

But you can also use update as update: Simply add IF EXISTS; to your query. But remember one thing: It's a big performance killer. Cassandra has to read all values from all nodes!

Comment: Yeah . I got it. Thanks